# Matching momentJS objects don't 'equal' in jasmine test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, momentjs, karma-jasmine

I have a suite of Jasmine tests as part of my angular-cli based project. One of my assertions is:

```
expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  type: 'SET_RANGE', payload: { value: 'Weekly', start: moment('2017-04-24'), end: moment() }
});
```

However, I get the following error.

> Expected spy dispatch to have been called with [ Object({ type: 'SET_RANGE', payload: Object({ value: 'Weekly', start: Mon Apr 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100, end: Sat Apr 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 }) }) ] but actual calls were [ Object({ type: 'SET_RANGE', payload: Object({ value: 'Weekly', start: Mon Apr 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100, end: Sat Apr 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 }) }) ]

Obviously these are displayed the same, but I have faced this issue elsewhere, where some property of the momentJS object doesn't match. So I would usually use:

```
expect(moment('2017-01-01').format()).toEqual(moment('2017-01-01').format())
```

But I can't use the `format()` bit when using `).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, show the code you're testing and tests themselves, there may be better ways to test it. Where does dispatchSpy come from? Obviously, `moment()` won't be even loosely equal to `moment()` - they can refer to different moments of time. A good way is to stub `moment` (it should be injectable for that).

Answer (score 2):

You can test partial object equality with [`jasmine.objectContaining`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.objectContaining%3C/code%3E). As pointed by @Dave Bush you need manual checks for moment objects. You can create a custom matcher for that with the use of [jasmine custom matcher](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html) and [`moment().isSame`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/).

Here is an example test wrote is JavaScript using Jasmine 2:

```
describe('Moment containing object', function () {   

    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.addMatchers({
            toBeEqualMoment: function () {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, expected) {
                        let result = {};
                        result.pass = actual.isSame(expected);
                        return result;
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    });

    it('is equal to moment containg object', function () {
        let input = {type: 'SET_RANGE', payload: { value: 'Weekly', start: moment('2017-04-24'), end: moment() }};
        let fooSpy = jasmine.createSpy('foo');

        fooSpy(input);

        let joc = jasmine.objectContaining;
        expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(joc({type: 'SET_RANGE', payload: joc({value: 'Weekly'})}));
        let spyCallParam = fooSpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
        expect(spyCallParam.payload.start).toBeEqualMoment(input.payload.start);
        expect(spyCallParam.payload.end).toBeEqualMoment(input.payload.end);
    });

});
```

[**Run on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1ww0cvob/1/)

For more information about custom matchers I recommend [this article](https://medium.com/@boriscoder/the-hidden-power-of-jest-matchers-f3d86d8101b0) by @boriscoder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are comparing two different pointers instead of two different values.

What I normally do in this case is create the object before the expect...

`let date = moment('2017-01-01');
expect(date).toEqual(date);`

If you have control over the object that is ultimately going to be used with `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` you can modify the code so you are comparing pointers.

Otherwise, you may have to go low level and get the parameter that was passed using calls.argsFor(index) and compare that to the format() like you normally do.